# How can I create a 3D rotating cylinder effect in a 2D game?

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to replicate the background effect seen in this video:

https://youtu.be/5mdICmKX94A?t=14m18s

I'm using libGDX and have only done 2D game dev using this framework. Is there some sort of cheat I can do in 2D to simulate this effect, or do I need to create a 3D cylinder, tile the inside of the cylinder with repeating textures, then rotate it with the camera in the middle?

Comment: Without knowing what engine/framework was used to make that game, I can only guess. I believe that was done in a 3D engine based on the camera's projection in relation to the background. The only cylinder effect that I know of in 2D would be a cylinder laid down as if you were looking through it, with the texture rotating.

Comment: After a little more research, I found that the engine used is a 2D engine based on a 3D framework. For reference, the engines name is 'Multimedia Fusion 2'